# MessageBox в c++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::MessageBox(NULL, s.str(), "Количество дней когдя 0" , MessageBoxButtons::OK);
```

в этой строчке ошибка
MessageBox: no overloaded function takes 4 arguments

Comment: Перевод: нет перегруженной функции, которая бы принимала 4 аргумента. Читайте описание к функции MessageBox, как её правильно использовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор буквально говорит вам, что в составе класса `MessageBox` нет функции с именем `MessageBox` и четырмя параметрами. Открыв соответствующую [страницу в МСДН](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.100).aspx) вы можете убедится в этом сами.

Видимо ваш код предполагает использование статической функции `Show` того же класса, в этом случае ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(NULL, s.str(), "Количество дней когдя 0" , MessageBoxButtons::OK);
```

Comment: теперь выдает ошибку: System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show : none of the 21 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: Я просто хочу в message вывести полученное число как это сделать